If Act A repeals another Act B, and Act A is repealed, what happens to the Act B?
I have the following scenario in mind.
Act A repealed Act B. Act C repeals Act A. What happens to Act B — does it remain repealed?
Let's assume that Act C doesn't mention anything about Act B.
This is a practical example, as The Statute Law Revision Act 1861 repealed several hundred statutes, but according to Wikipedia it was repealed by the Statute Law (Repeals) Act 1998.

This might be better suited for law.stackexchange.com

Unless the originally repealed act is explicitly reinstated, it remains repealed.
Section 15 of the Interpretation Act 1978 (Repeal of repeal) says

Where an Act repeals a repealing enactment, the repeal does not revive any enactment previously repealed unless words are added reviving it.


Of course, then the question becomes, what happens if you repeal the Interpretation Act of 1978...

@kenod - almost certainly the common law works the same way. The usual explanation is that the repealing Act has now had an effect (repealing). It now longer needs to function having done its work. The earlier act has had its status changed. Unless the repealing Act worked very oddly (eg by saying "so long as this Act is in force, the XXXX Act shall have no effect" or something like that).

@kenod Parliament disappears in a puff of logic.

@FrancisDavey: It's not terribly unusual, at least in the USA, for legilsation to render other laws ineffective until a specified date.  I wouldn't be surprised if legislation has specified that some other law will be ineffective until some particular event transpires.  It would seem weird for legislation to make some other law ineffective indefinitely, but the notion of "so long as this act is in force, XXX shall have no effect", with XXX automatically coming back into effect when the disabling act ceases to be in force, is sometimes the most logical way of handling unexpected situations.

@kenod: You get everybody mad at you for inadvertently creating an ex-post-facto law. The UK can have them in certain circumstances; but they really should be regarded as requiring explicit language to do so because they are abominations.

@FrancisDavey There have indeed been suspensory acts (in contrast to repeal acts) in the UK and elsewhere, perhaps most famously related Habeus Corpus.

@kenod, I think there is potentially an ambiguity in the word "repeal" - most commonly in relation to an Act of Parliament, it is most naturally going to mean "terminate any further effect of" rather than "treat as if it had never been made". If a repealing act is itself repealed, then it simply leaves a void again as if no relevant Act is in force, and where the judiciary then have a free hand to decide the case - it doesn't revive the effect of previous Acts, which should already be forgotten. (1/2)

If the Interpretation Act were repealed, then it would simply fall to the judge to decide the point of what the law is. A lot of people forget that the law is ultimately whatever a judge says it is. The King was originally the ultimate statute lawmaker and final judge of appeal, and only later were these functions formally delegated (in reality, appropriated during political changes) to different bodies, in which there could be a possibility of inconsistent policy. (2/2)

It is worth noting that an Act whose only effect is to repeal previous enactments, change the titles of previous enactments, or otherwise change the status of previous enactments is generally considered "spent" as soon as it comes into force: its effect has been achieved (changing the status of other enactments), it does not have a continuing effect. It is the normal course of business for Parliament to repeal spent Acts in a later Statute Law (Repeals) Act. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spent_enactment
